# How to avoid tedious null checks on an object

Tags: java, null, encapsulation

If I have a class that I want to accept an optional logger to log debug information:

```
public class A {

private Logger logger ; 

public A( Logger logger ) { 
    this.logger = logger ; 
}

public A() { 
    this( null ) ;
}

public void hello() {
    logger.debug( "hello" ) ;
}

public void goodbye() {
    logger.warn( "goodbye" ) ; 
}

}
```

Is there any way for me to avoid the need for constant null checks?

```
public void hello() {

    if( logger != null ) { 
        logger.debug( "hello" ) ;
    }

}

public void goodbye() {

    if( logger != null ) {
        logger.warn( "goodbye" ) ; 
    }

}
```

I thought maybe if I made a logger wrapper class, that could do the checks for me and then either do nothing, or log the message. But then I would need to wrap each method I would want to use.

Comment: Is it intended that logger can be set to null? Or are you just defensive coding?  Is a null logger the way you want to "turn off" logging?

Comment: It's intended, yes; I would like to make an object that will output messages using a logger if one is provided, but don't output anything if there isn't one.

Comment: again then make a custom impl, that has all its `warn/info/debug` methods totally empty.

Answer (score 9):

I would create `Logger` as an interface and implement the real logger and a dummy class that doesn't log anything. This way, you can always just access the logger without any null checks.

Answer (score 4):

All answers basically suggest using *Null Object pattern*, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern
- [Null Object Pattern to avoid Null checks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952195/null-object-pattern-to-avoid-null-checks)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this maybe:

```
private void logDebug(final String str, final Object ... parameters ) {
    if (this.logger != null && this.logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        this.logger.debug(
           parameters.length > 0
              ? MessageFormat.format(str, parameters)
              : str
        );
    }
}

private void logInfo(final String str,final Object ... parameters) {
    if (this.logger != null && this.logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
        this.logger.info(
           parameters.length > 0
              ? MessageFormat.format(str, parameters)
              : str
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can just call `logDebug(str)` or `logInfo(str)`, and you can also interpolate the log messages with parameters using [`MessageFormat.format()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
logDebug("Called {0} method with parameters {1} and {2}","doStuff",foo,bar);
```

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

1. always initialize the logger

   (and/or) use a sentinel logger that doesn't to anything at all

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if it sounds dumb, but won't making the methods Warn and Debug static solve this ?
If you need an instance just create it inside the static methods, or if its a singleton check forr null inside the static methods.

Comment: Exactly, the famous singleton pattern :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a boolean "enableLogging" to true in your 1-parameter constructor, and to false in your empty constructor. Thus you give more meaning to your checks - and they are faster.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is you are using null everywhere, which means naturally you need to test for null everywhere. Create a Logger where all methods do nothing and use that instance where appropriate.